# Quotation marks not shown on display

Tags: android, html, xml

In my string xml file I have a line like this:

```
<string name="infoHeader">random "text" here</string>
```

But it is only displayed as

> random text here

on the phone's display, that is, without the quotation marks.

I read about it via Google, and tried some HTML styling:

```
<string name="infoHeader">random &quot;text&quot; here</string>
```

And then used:

```
String hej = res.getString(R.string.infoHeader);     
Spanned marked_up = Html.fromHtml(hej);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.infoHeader)).setText(marked_up, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

But it still doesn't work. I tried some other HTML, like `&lt;i>text&lt;/i>`, and that works just fine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<string name="infoHeader">random \"text\" here</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Weird I couldn't find that simple trick on the net.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  Value:  \"Hello\"
```

in the resources window, or

```
<string name="hello">\&quot;Hello\&quot;</string>
```

in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on, but I tried a few other ways of escaping.

This worked for me:

```
<string name="hello">Hello \"World,\" ActivityHello!</string>
```